# Send back value to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

Problem, is, if in x.php file I do following:

```
print_r($data->name);
```

then I get in Ajax call console.log(data); (Right data), but if I don't do print_r, I get null. I dont really want to `print_r($data)` in `x.php`, I just want to pass the value (without printing on screen) back to ajax function, so `console.log($data)` would show correct data and then manipulate it there with some html. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to print it, thats how your javascript takes result.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
exit();
```

Comment: I still get printed value on screen. Is it supposed to happen? I edited my original post. Take a look, please.

Comment: Don't print_r() anything! The json_encode turns the array into something javascript can read and turn into a javascript object

Comment: get rid of the loop too. just json encode filterData and send that

Comment: You don't want to avoid that. Otherwise nothing gets returned to JavaScript!

Comment: What is this doing? $filterData = classX::filterData(); You set $data as $_POST, but don't use it. Then you loop through $filterData, replacing $data with each array element of $filterData. You don't pass $data to $filterData, so I'm struggling to see how this will even work.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['data'])){

        $data = $_POST['data'];

        $filterData = classX::filterData(); // What does this do? I don't see $data being passed to it

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($filterData); // I assume the data from $_POST['data'] is in $filteredData, filtered and validated
        exit();
    }

Comment: I updated foreach loop with comments (xdebugger results). Now I do not get anything printed (which is great), but also nothing in console appears (not so great).

$data will hold where conditions I will pass in filterData(..) for future. Right now I test filterData - which returns json elements. I test filterData functionality before adding where conditions when selecting data.

Comment: Why are you looping? You overwrite $data on each loop

Comment: Var dumping will invalidate your JSON too.

Comment: I updated once again. Still empty console. Do you need to see filterData() as well?

Comment: Yes, it looks like your post data isn't being passed? Can you show me the code for uit?

Comment: Updated! Feel free to update your answer using my example data, so it's more clear how to deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldnt I have dataType: text not json in ajax call?